# moving files to different directories

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu

I'm trying to move media and other files which are in a specified directory to another directory and create another one if it does not exits (where the files will go), and create a directory the remaining files with different extensions will go. My first problem is that my script is not making a new directory and it is not moving the files to other directories and what code can I use to move files with different extensions to one directory?

This is what i have had so far, correct me where I'm wrong and help modify my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
From=/home/katy/doc
To=/home/katy/mo #directory where the media files will go
WA=/home/katy/do # directory where the other files will go
 if [ ! -d "$To" ]; then
   mkdir -p "$To"
 fi
cd $From
find path -type f -name"*.mp4" -exec mv {} $To \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd solve it somewhat like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
From=/home/katy/doc
To=/home/katy/mo # directory where the media files will go
WA=/home/katy/do # directory where the other files will go

cd "$From"
find . -type f \
| while read file; do
    dir="$(dirname "$file")"
    base="$(basename "$file")"
    if [[ "$file" =~ \.mp4$ ]]; then
      target="$To"
    else
      target="$WA"
    fi
    mkdir -p "$target/$dir"
    mv -i "$file" "$target/$dir/$base"
  done
```

Notes:

- `mkdir -p` will not complain if the directory already exists, so there's no need to check for that.
- Put double quotes around all filenames in case they contain spaces.
- By piping the output of `find` into a `while` loop, you also avoid getting bitten by spaces, because `read` will read until a newline.
- You can modify the regex according to taste, e.g. `\.(mp3|mp4|wma|ogg)$`.
- In case you didn't know, `$(...)` will run the given command and stick its output back in the place of the `$(...)` (called *command substitution*). It is almost the same as `` `...` `` but slightly better ([details](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html)).
- In order to test it, put `echo` in front of `mv`. (Note that quotes will disappear in the output.)

Answer (score 1):

```
cd $From
find . -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec mv {} $To \;
    ^^^
```

or

```
find $From -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec mv {} $To \;
     ^^^^^
```

Comment: im trying but its not working an error is showing can not mv:no such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

```
cd $From  
mv *.mp4 $To;  
mv * $WA;
```

Comment: its telling me target not a directory